# Best way to share user/request data between layers in asp.net core/ web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata, clean-architecture, onion-architecture

Best way to share user/request data between layers in asp.net core/ web api.
I want to share/propagate the user/request data from Controller to Service, then Service to Repository.

I can use IHttpContextAccessor to use the http context and add items to dictionary to save user information. But, I need to inject it everywhere where I need that information and this is not good practice to use Http refence to Service or Repository layer.

Same challenge with OData, how to pass Odata parameters to from controller to service and then service to repository without passing explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If the data that you want to pass down the chain is not in the parameter of the controller method but is in the HttpContext properties instead, then I'd create a service that hold that information and populate it from middleware.

1. Create a custom service that holds the information needed down the chain.
2. Register that service as scoped.
3. Create some middleware that will read the incoming request context and populate your custom service with the relevant information.
4. Add that middleware to the pipeline.
5. Inject your custom service into your lower layers instead of an IHttpContextAccessor.
6. Your lower layers then get their values from your custom service.

This will decouple your lower layers from HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach according to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-httpcontext-from-custom-components, it is best to register  and  inject Http Context dependency in the required layer using built-in DI container

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34554233)